# Groovy - How to address No signature of method error

Tags: apache-kafka, groovy

Beginner in Groovy, so please excuse, if it is a straight forward scenario.

I came up with a simple script to consume messages from Kafka but it reports the below error message. I tried to Google the error but can't wrap my head around the solutions provided.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), chars(), any(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure), take(int)
        at consumer.run(Consumer.groovy:8)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

**Consumer.groovy**

```
@Grab(group='org.apache.kafka', module='kafka-clients', version='2.8.0')
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

def props = new Properties()
props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
props.setProperty("group.id", "sample-group")
props.setProperty("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.name())
props.setProperty("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.name())

def consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props)
consumer.subscribe(["test-topic"])

while (true) {
  def records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100))
  for (def record : records) {
    println("Received message: ${record.value()}")
  }
}
```

Comment: which line is that -> `Consumer.groovy:8`?

Comment: @injecteer : `props.setProperty("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.name())`

Comment: Just remove`()` after `StringDeserializer.name`

Comment: or use `StringDeserializer.getName()`

Comment: @daggett Tried that, thank you, now facing
`SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Duration for class: Consumer
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Duration for class: Consumer
        at Consumer.run(Consumer.groovy:15)`

Offending line -- `def records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100))`

Comment: @injecteer & @daggett:  Now I modified `def records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100)` to `records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100)` and next line as well, hit with a new error - 
`/root/work/Consumer.groovy: 16: Java-style for-each statement requires a type declaration.;
   solution: Use the 'in' keyword, as for (x in y) {...} @ line 16, column 16.
     for ( record : records) {`

Comment: 1. you must import `java.time.Duration`, as it's not imported automatically by Groovy. 
2. you should be using `records.each{ record -> println "..." }`

Comment: @injecteer : this `import java.time.Duration` fixed it, thanks a lot

Comment: Feel free to answer your own post below rather than in comments